# Visual studio 2017 and Xamarin.iOS can not open project settings->iOS Build tab

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I have problems to open the iOS Build tab in the iOS project settings in Visual studio 2017.
On first opening I got the error: "Path cannot be null. Parameter name: path"
On the second opening I get the error: "An error occurred trying to load the page.Unable to create the designer. File is already opened in an incompatible editor."

[image]
Can anybody help me?

Have some more info:

The problem occurs because I split up my Info.plist file in Info-beta.plist, Info-release.plist to have different package names for different configurations. I add them in the .csproj file as

```
<None Include="Info-beta.plist" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Beta' ">
      <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
    </None>
    <None Include="Info-debug.plist" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
      <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
    </None>
```

Still I do not know how to solve the problem with the different .plist files per configuration.

The only solution what I found is:

Keep the Info.plist file for the Release configuration and the other files like Info-debug.plist file for the Debug config etc.. But in the iOS Build tab you only see the info from the Info.plist no matter which configuration you are selecting.

Comment: Did this issue only happen when the Mac agent was not connected?

Comment: It's happening also when the mac agent is connected. Also all other tabs can be viewed just the iOS Build tab not.

Comment: Have you updated the version of Visual Studio for Mac and Visual Studio in PC to the latest version?

Comment: Yes I'm on the latest version on both side. Also looked into the .csproj file with an editor but did not found anything wrong there...